# ERROR reflect.ValueOf(val).IsZero undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method IsZero

Tags: go, reflection, go-gorm

I want to use [gorm](https://gorm.io/) in my code but when I run `go run *.go`, I see this Error, unfortunately.

```
/var/www/html/src/gorm.io/gorm/utils/utils.go:46:30: reflect.ValueOf(val).IsZero undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method IsZero)
```

this is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code  string
    Price uint
}

func main() {
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
}

// Migrate the schema
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})

// Create
db.Create(&Product{Code: "D42", Price: 100})
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace for better understanding

Comment: Unrelated, but you should never be running a project with `go run *.go`. See https://golang.org/doc/code.html to get started.

Comment: @jimB thanks. Yes, but I just wanted to debug the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Value.IsZero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsZero) method was added in Go 1.13. You have to use Go 1.13 or a later version if your code relies on this "feature".

You can check your go version by running `go version`.